# Issues Reading a table from Geodatabase

Tags: python, arcpy, file-geodatabase

I have scripted a process to read a CSV file into a file geodatabase. Then, I want to read this imported file and work on it by adding new fields and calculating values. However, while using the arcpy.ListTables() on the geodatabase does not list the table.

I am just confused what is wrong.

Any help !!

Here is my script

```
outLocation = dbLoc+'\\'+ out_name +'.gdb'

# Make list of all tables in workspace
tables = arcpy.ListTables("GDB*")

print tables
try:

    for tb in tables:
    # Execute TableToGeodatabase
        print "Importing "+tb+ " to gdb: " + outLocation
        arcpy.TableToGeodatabase_conversion(tables, outLocation)

env.workspace = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))+'\\'+ out_name +'.gdb'
arcpy.RefreshCatalog(env.workspace)

inTables = arcpy.ListTables()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List tables uses the env.workspace setting, you are also asking for all tables that start with `'gdb'`.

```
outLocation = dbLoc+"\\"+ out_name +".gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = where_tables_are # the folder where your tables are
tables = arcpy.ListTables("GDB*.csv") # all tables starting with GDB, is this right
for tb in tables:
    # get the base name for the table
    # fred.csv becomes outTbName="fred", notUsed=".csv"
    outTbName,notUsed = os.path.splitext(tb)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Converting " + tb + " to " + outTbName)
    # clear the way for the new table
    if arcpy.Exists(outLocation + "\\" + outTbName):
        arcpy.AddMessage("Clearing " + outTbName)
        arcpy.Delete_management(outLocation + "\\" + outTbName)

    # copy the input rows
    arcpy.CopyRows_management(tb,outLocation + "\\" + outTbName)
# file is not defined, so set it to outLocation instead
# env.workspace = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(file))+"\\"+ out_name +".gdb"   
arcpy.env.workspace = outLocation
arcpy.RefreshCatalog(env.workspace)

inTables = arcpy.ListTables()
```

inTables should now be a list of all the tables in the geodatabase.

Comment: Michael, I tried your method and did specify the work space for my initial input files. So I was able to import all the files to the geodatabase. When i open the geodatabse via ArcGIS, I can see the imported tables. However when i try to read the tables from this geodatabse and list them the imported table are not listed.    # all tables starting with GDB, is this right (yes this is correct)

Comment: I'm not so sure about your workspace, os.path.dir... so set it instead to outLocation.

Comment: Ok. So I did check the workspace. As defined, it points to the correct GDB --> C:\Work\Projects\0b_CA_SFBayArea\Segmenter_v7\00001 CA San Francisco San Jose 2013.gdb. Also note that the listing statement lists two other tables already present in the geodatabase. Do you think there is something with importing csv.

Comment: CSV can be a bit funny. To be safe I've used python file I/O to read and InsertCursor to put them into a database. Do you have Microsoft Access (or similar open office utility) by any chance?

Comment: I think its a CSV issue also, but cannot figure out what ? The script imports the table all OK. I can open it and see it. Yes, I have MS access, Postgres etc.

Comment: Perhaps the wildcard isn't working properly, I've edited the list tables to include the extension. The tables all start with GDB and end in .csv like GDB_data.csv right? I've had much better results importing CSV into personal geodatabase (.mdb) using Access than with ArcGis tools. Perhaps echo the tables like arcpy.addmessage(tables) to see if there are any returned.

Comment: I would have used personal geodatabase, but my files are HUGE. I will easily exceed the size limit.

Comment: The add message gives me the Table name. Same table that it is importing. [u'GDB_HBW.csv']

Comment: another observation. When the table is imported to the database say its named 'GDB_HBW_csv' i renamed the filed to '_x' and python was able to read it. Confused !!!!

Comment: Its was the input file name that was a problem. I renamed the input file to x_HBW and it works all fine. Seems like GDB is a reserved word or something. The final solution is So After working with Michael, I found that the input file name was an issue. I was importing a file with words GDB in the prefix. Import was going on ok, but python was not reading the resultant input file named 'GDB_xxxx'. 

So i renamed my input file to 'xxx_test' and everything is working fine. Seems like GDB is a reserved word or something .

Comment: yes, gdb is reserved, I should have picked up on that (Doh!). Also tables can't start with a number or underscore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the environment workspace to your input geodatabase  before you call the ListTables line. Also I don't believe gdb* is a valid parameter, look at the help file to see the valid parameters.

Comment: "GDB*" is the wildcard, see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000002t000000 it is valid.

Comment: My mistake I was interpreting "gdb*" as the _table_type_ parameter! Thanks for correcting me.